# PB 12 IDE (and Application) crash after closing

Tags: crash, powerbuilder

Good Morning,

I seem to be experiencing an issue with both our PowerBuilder 12.1 Classic (Build 6639) and our resulting PowerBuilder Application. We are currently experiencing an issue where the application (or, if we are running through the code, the IDE) crashes after closing the main MDI. Unfortunately, there is no consistent pattern to the crash. I can close it right as the MDI opens and sometimes it will crash, other times it will close properly.

Initially, I had figured that there was something going wrong with the Application object's close event, or something is happening where the systemerror event is being thrown. I debugged through the close event and every single line executed successfully, but the application still crashed.

I thought I would try and use the /PBDEBUG flag on the application and try to get the debug information for a successful close and an unsuccessful close. I managed to do so, and the file contains the exact same information. They all finish with the following information:

```
  Executing object function +DESTROY for class TRANSACTION, lib entry _TYPEDEF
      Executing instruction at line 2325
      Executing object function DESTROYTRANSACTION for class TRANSACTION, lib entry _TYPEDEF
          Executing system dll function
      End class function DESTROYTRANSACTION for class TRANSACTION, lib entry _TYPEDEF
      Executing instruction at line 2326
  End class function +DESTROY for class TRANSACTION, lib entry _TYPEDEF
```

I checked the Windows Application Event Viewer, and this is what gets displayed:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: txintf.exe
P2: 11.1.18.1
P3: 4cec7a53
P4: System
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 506c18e6
P7: 2d4a
P8: 36
P9: System.ObjectDisposedException
P10:
```

I was told that these issues started to occur when we migrated our PB11 project over to PB12 Classic. Not sure if that has anything to do with it, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or have any additional tips that I can use to attempt to diagnose this problem?

Thank you.

EDIT: I've noticed that sometimes the Error is being shown in the Windows Event Log, and here is some of the information:

```
Faulting application name: txintf.exe, version: 13.0.2.3, time stamp: 0x4cec7a53
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b83c8a
Exception code: 0xe0434f4d
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x2120
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce0099b3021b60
Faulting application path: MyApplicationPath\txintf.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
```

There are also some rare times when the Just-In-Time Debugger pops up, showing that an exception of System.ObjectDisposedException has been caught. Judging by that information, it looks like there is an object that has been destroyed that is being accessed by something.

I checked the Call Stack through the debugger, and it doesn't appear to have anything after the Application.Close() event.

Comment: Any autoinstantiated globals?

Comment: None that I have seen thus far.

Comment: Correction: We do have two autoinstantiated global variables, both of which are structures. Both of them contain a number of strings, booleans, integers, and longs. One of them contains an Array of Any

Comment: I'm not sure if structures fall into the same category, but autoinstantiated non-visual user objects as globals are known to cause problems on app closing.

Comment: Added some additional information

Comment: Since we are using PowerBuilder 12.1 (Build 6639), we only have the option to create the application as 32-bit. Why would the application be accessing the x64 KernelBase.dll (SysWOW64) rather than the 32-bit version in the System 32 folder?

Comment: In 64-bit Windows systems, the System32 folder contains 64-bit files. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff955767.aspx

Comment: I think you might have been onto something, maybe it is trying to be destroyed after it has been destroyed. Maybe wrap the destroy statement in a try catch exception block as a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object destruction brings me back to my theory, and reminded me of one other case I found once. It was a non-autoinstantiated NVO, with an autoinstantiated NVO as an instance variable. Yes, it sounds like I'm beating a dead horse, but it's the only case I've ever heard of. One debugging idea is to put a line of script in the Destructor event of all objects (they're all inherited, right?), put a breakpoint there, and try to narrow down what objects are or are not part of the problem.

Comment: Yup, it was exactly as you described. There was a non-autoinstantiated NVO that contained an autoinstantiated NVO as an instance variable. Cleaned up the code and the crashing stopped.

Comment: Yes, it's a frustrating and, as in your case, sometimes a difficult to diagnose bug. It's been there for ages; I wish it would get fixed. Glad you solved your problem.